# Windows stretching over taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, taskbar

So as you can see in the screenshot, my Windows is basically scaling the full vertical width of the monitor and I have had to hide the task bar because it simply overlaps every window. Basically I want everything to fit in-between the top of the screen and the top of the task bar, the way it previously was. 
[image]

Any help on this situation is greatly appreciated as I don't even know what to query to find a solution to this. I accidentally dropped something on my keyboard and it must have pressed the correct combination for this to happen and I don't know how to undo it.

Comment: The only reason for this I can think of is that you have launched Chrome in Windows 8 mode instead of Desktop mode. If you click the little lines button on the top right to bring down the menu and on this there should be an option to 'relaunch chrome in desktop mode'

Comment: No I don't think that is the case. This happens with every application and hasn't reset even when restarting PC. Also, the option says "Reopen Chrome in Windows 8 mode".

Comment: Hmm strange, what happens if you hover the mouse over the taskbar, right click and go to properties check what is set here. Things like Auto-Hide the taskbar, etc. are they ticked?

Comment: Did you use any tools to enable borderless fullscreenmode for games like autohotkey scripts or some special program?

Comment: @CharlesH Basically, I have to have this checked or it covers the bottom parts of my applications. Lock the taskbar is checked, and so is autohide.

Comment: @Syberdoor I have used no third party program to do anything of the sorts. I have a basic Macro key setup using Logitechs gaming software but they are binded to "/all GG" etc.. for LoL so I don't think that these would have caused an issue.